# Как запустить с from inport python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Делаю мини программку. И решил разделить по нескольким файлам разные функции.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю уже импорт с файлом `plus.py`
И в итоге если вставляю сверху `from programs.calculator.functions.plus import*` то ничего не работает. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но при том что `prints.py` и `tutor.py` работают
Если вставляю уже тут где он находится то далее `number` `plus_one` и `plus_two` [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при том что можно ввести числа и происходит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если убрать строку с `from programs.calculator.functions.plus import*` То далее программа идёт

Как мне сделать так чтобы смог и импортнуть и запустить те функции с файла `plus.py` которые мне нужны
Вот он сам [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто сейчас для себя разбираю о том чтобы активировать функции из разных файлов в одном когда это нужно будет. Но застрял именно на этом. Сможете помочь?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 2):

То что вы решили разбить код на файлы - вполне нормальная практика. Но разложить по папкам файлы в питоне - мало, он ведь должен точно знать что именно импортировать. В данном случае, он просто не смог найти файл, указывающий что в такой-то папке находится пакет, который вы будете импортировать.
Чтобы такого не было - надо явно помечать, что хотите чтобы папка считалась пакетом. Для этого достаточно в дирректорию положить пустой файл `__init__.py`

Файлы с именем `__init__.py` используются для маркировки каталогов на диске в виде каталогов пакетов Python.

```
.
├── programs
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── calculator
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── functions
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── plus.py
└── test.py
```

в модуле plus.py к примеру:

```
def plus(a, b):
  return a + b
```

в файле test.py:

```
from programs.calculator.functions.plus import *

print(plus(1 , 2))
```

в консоли выведет `3`

Более подробно можно почитать на [хекслете](https://ru.hexlet.io/courses/python-basics/lessons/packages/theory_unit) к примеру: